# Convert CURL php script to python code

Tags: python, http, post

I need to convert this php function, which use CURL to login to an web server and then request a png resource.

```
function GraphImageById ($graphid, $period = 3600, $width, $height) { global $z_server, $z_user, $z_pass, $z_tmp_cookies, $z_url_index, $z_url_graph, $z_url_api, $z_img_path,   $z_login_data;
    // file names
    $filename_cookie = $z_tmp_cookies ."zabbix_cookie_" .$graphid .".txt";
    $image_name = $z_img_path ."zabbix_graph_" .$graphid .".png";

    //setup curl
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $z_url_index);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $z_login_data);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $filename_cookie);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $filename_cookie);
    // login - 1st curl exec.
    curl_exec($ch);
    // get graph
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $z_url_graph ."?graphid=" .$graphid ."&width=" .$width ."&height=" .$height ."&period=" .$period);
    // set response header
    header("Content-type: image/png");
    $output = curl_exec($ch); // - 2nd curl exec.
    curl_close($ch);
    unlink($filename_cookie);
    return $output;
```

}

Which python lib I can use? Any suggestions?
Thanks.

Comment: SO is not a code writing service. What do you have so far? What problems do you have?

Comment: I need to post my auth data to the server, save cookie response and make a new request to another "php file" to get a png resource.

Answer (score 1):

Probably pycurl (cURL lib binding for python) is what you want (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pycurl), but i'm pretty sure you also can approach this with httplib/httplib2.

Comment: At this time I've solved with python "requests" module.

Comment: Good, request is an awesome module by the way!